# Different outputs with numpy.where function based on how array is defined; duplicated first index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I just started learning Numpy with the purpose of speeding up my iterations. I'm trying to understand what's going on with my code here. Basically I just want to print every tuple in a list of tuples using a vectorized lambda function. I have two different versions of my code:

Input v1:

```
elist = [(0, 'G-001'), (1, 'G-004'), (2, 'G-007'), (3, 'G-008'), (4, 'G-009')]

array = np.array(elist)
print(type(array))
insert = np.vectorize(lambda x: print(x))
np.where(insert(array))
```

Output v1:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
0
0
G-001
1
G-004
2
G-007
3
G-008
4
G-009
```

I don't understand why it's printing the first index twice and why it's also printing every element of each tuple on a new line.

Compare to this:

Input v2:

```
elist = [(0, 'G-001'), (1, 'G-004'), (2, 'G-007'), (3, 'G-008'), (4, 'G-009')]

array = pd.Series(elist).values
print(type(array))
insert = np.vectorize(lambda x: print(x))
np.where(insert(array))
```

Output v2:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(0, 'G-001')
(0, 'G-001')
(1, 'G-004')
(2, 'G-007')
(3, 'G-008')
(4, 'G-009')
```

Okay, one issue down, although I'm still getting the duplicated first index.

For some reason, casting my list of tuples as a pandas series and then calling the values attribute gives me the result I want. I'm confused because doing this also makes a numpy.ndarray object and I don't know how this is functionally different from my v1. I'm still new to Numpy and I know that vectorization produces a duplicate function call which is probably I'm getting that duplicate first index, but is there any to programmatically prevent the return from being output?

Any help and insight is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They return different things because they are different things. Since a `Series` object is essentially a 1D column, you are telling `pandas` to create an 1D array of tuples, as opposed to a 2D array. See code below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

elist = [(0, 'G-001'), (1, 'G-004'), (2, 'G-007'), (3, 'G-008'), (4, 'G-009')]

arr2 = pd.Series(elist).values
arr1 = np.array(elist)

print(arr1, arr1.shape)
print(arr2, arr2.shape)
insert = np.vectorize(lambda x: None)
print(np.where(insert(arr1)), '\n', np.where(insert(arr2)))

>>[['0' 'G-001']
 ['1' 'G-004']
 ['2' 'G-007']
 ['3' 'G-008']
 ['4' 'G-009']] (5, 2)
[(0, 'G-001') (1, 'G-004') (2, 'G-007') (3, 'G-008') (4, 'G-009')] (5,)
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64)) 
 (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: Oh makes sense, I had been making arrays out of lists with single elements until now so I thought the arrays were supposed to be 1D by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mstaino for clarifying why I was getting different outputs.

I found out how to prevent the first index from printing twice after I came across this Github bug report: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8758

Basically, the 'otypes' argument must be populated with the appropriate datatype for the data that is passed as an argument to the vectorized function.

Ie:

```
insert = np.vectorize(lambda x: print(x), otypes = [tuple])
```